# Proof of archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to self-study Baby Rudin (and it's proving quite challenging to me)

Could someone clarify where the underlined part comes from?

[image]

Text:

> (a) If $x \in R, y \in R,$ and $x > 0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$.
>
> **Proof** (a) Let $A$ be the set of all $nx$, where $n$ runs through the positive integers.  If (a) were false, then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$.  But then $A$ has a *least* upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$.  Put $\alpha = \sup A$.  Since $x > 0$, $\alpha - x < \alpha$, and $\alpha - x$ is not an upper bound of $A$.  $\underline{\text{Hence $\alpha - x < mx$ for some positive integer $m$}}$.  But then $\alpha < (m+1)x \in A$, which is impossible, since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since $\alpha -x$ is not an upper bound of $A$, there must be an element in $A$, call it $mx$, bigger than $\alpha-x$, namely $\alpha -x < mx$. It is the logical negation of the property of being an upper bound for a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Just after negating $\alpha - x \ge nx$, I realized how stupid I am. Thanks

Comment: i don't think that's why. The reason why there is `mx` is because the distance between $\alpha - x$ and $\alpha$ is exactly $x$, so no matter where $\alpha$ is, the interval is large enough to have one multiple of $x$ land in it, kinda like a pidgeonhole principle. You could probably prove it as a separate lemma, $\forall x > 0,\alpha > x \exists n, \alpha - x \leq nx \leq \alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

We know $\alpha$ - $x$ is not an upper bound of $A$. i.e. there exists some element of A greater than $\alpha - x$. So let this element, greater than $\alpha - x$ be written as $mx$ for some m, an element of the postive integers. So then $\alpha -x \lt mx$.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems far simpler to me, but there must be something wrong if Rudin doesn't include it. Maybe the $\lceil$ceiling$\rceil$ function is not defined yet? Thoughts?

Statement:

If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x >0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx>y$.

Proof:

Given $x,y>0$,
let $n=\lceil{\frac{y+1}{x}}\rceil$. Then,

\begin{align*}
nx&= \lceil {\frac{y+1}{x}} \rceil \cdot x \\
&\ge y+1\\
&>y.
\end{align*}
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

Comment: Indeed, the definition of the ceiling function is $\lceil x \rceil =$ the least integer $n$ such that $n \ge x$, so if you haven't yet proved the existence of one such integer, then that definition is not applicable.